# get ID for a specific user in mysql database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

When a user signs in i want to echo back there ID (which is created because of the auto_increment in phpMyAdmin) from **there** account, here's my login.PHP:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("xxxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx", "BuyerAccounts");

$Email = $_POST["Email"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];


$sql_query = "select Buyer_Email from user_info where Buyer_Email like '$Email' and Buyer_Password like '$Password';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row["Buyer_Email"]; 
echo "Welcome: Buyer";

}else{
$int = 1;
//echo "Buyer login failed...";
}
}else{
echo "Login failed...";
}
}


mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

Comment: `SELECT ID, Buyer_Email FROM ...` (replace `ID` with your id field name)

Comment: ID is the name of the field in my DB and after do i just echo back ID because i don't want to select it i want to grab it when the user signs in and put the number in a variable so i can echo it back

Comment: after selection you can put it in a variable, as well as for email

Comment: @user6042879 Did I answer your question? If not, what can I add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the column name id in your sql query.let say your column name for id is **`ID`**

```
$sql_query = "select ID,Buyer_Email from user_info where Buyer_Email like '$Email' and Buyer_Password like '$Password';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row["Buyer_Email"]; 
$user_id =  $row['ID'];
echo $user_id;
echo "Welcome: Buyer";

}
```

Since your making login in php its good choice to use `$_SESSION`.
All you need to do is add a `session_start();` at the top of any php script where you need to use session.

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("xxxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx", "BuyerAccounts");

$Email = $_POST["Email"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];
 $sql_query = "select ID,Buyer_Email from user_info where Buyer_Email like '$Email' and Buyer_Password like '$Password';";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $name = $row["Buyer_Email"]; 
    $user_id =  $row['ID'];

    //using session
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;

    echo $user_id;
    echo "Welcome: Buyer";

    }
```

Now you can access anywhere in your php script using the `$_SESSION` variable.

```
echo $_SESSION["user_id"] ;
```

Comment: @ProgrammingTree Thank you. Your answer is also great that why i also upvoted it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the beginning. You create a login form, you store sessions based on the values:

**login.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
```

**main.page**

```
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
echo "Hi $username";
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok, so you want to check if username exists and then echo their ID. Regardless, almost all login systems have sessions.

After logging in, let's say you have a `$_SESSION` of **id**.

**php**

```
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION["id"];

$db = mysqli_connect("xxxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx", "BuyerAccounts");
$check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'"); 
$num_check = $check->num_rows; 
$fetch_check = $check->fetch_object();
$id2 = $fetch_check->id;

if($num_check) {
// User Exists
echo $id2; 
} else {
echo "You don't exist."
}
```

Please note, normally, I would just echo `$id`. However, the OP requested to echo the id from the db, so I echoed `$id2`.

Comment: OP wants “echo back there ID” from database. login is based on email and password. username doesn't exists (in OP question, maybe in db it exists).

Comment: in my code i check if the user exists and then i want to get there ID

Comment: @user6042879 Please see updated code. Does this answer your question? If not, what can I add?

Comment: the other guy answered it but thank you for the update, people like you who work hard on here is why its such a great website so i thank you for that